# for-loop over tuple in Python: ValueError

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a tuple of arrays like the following:

```
z = (array( [ [1], [2], [3]] ),
     array( [[10],[11],[12]] )
    )
```

I want to iterate over them with a simple for loop using two variables:

```
for x, y in z:
    print("it worked")
    self.doStuff(x, y)
```

... but it throws the error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I have googled this error. Many seem to suggest the .split() method or .items(). I'm not really sure, where to add those, since the don't belong to tuples. How can I execute this for-loop properly? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I assume you are trying to iterate over the arrays' elements, not over the tuple's elements, right? If so, you should re-think your data structures -- an iteration over a single 2-tuple unpacking 2 values results in a single run, where you unpack the 2 complete arrays from the tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the other answer it might be that I misunderstood what you want.

You can also use

```
for x,y in zip(*z):
```

to unzip the z tuple.

The output then is:

```
it worked
[1] [10]
it worked
[2] [11]
it worked
[3] [12]
```

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
for x, y in z:
```

assumes (at least in Python2.7), that each element in `z` can be [tuple unpacked](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/). This would be the case if each element in `z` is, say, a pair tuple:

```
In [23]: for x, y in [(1, 2), (3, 4)]:
    ...:     pass
    ...:
```

For your case, could it be that you simply want

```
x, y = z
```

?

This works by me:

```
In [19]: z = (array( [ [1], [2], [3]] ),
    ...:      array( [[10],[11],[12]] )
    ...:     )

In [20]: x, y = z

In [21]: x
Out[21]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])

In [22]: y
Out[22]: 
array([[10],
       [11],
       [12]])
```